# Replace test property values at the time of maven build

Tags: java, maven-3

I have a test.properties file located in: $PROJECT_HOME/src/test/resources with the following content:

```
hostname=${host}
```

I also have a main.properties file located in: $PROJECT_HOME/src/main/resources with the same content.

Then I specified the followinging lines in the pom-file of my project.

```
<properties>
    <host>localhost</host>
</properties>

<build>  
  <resources>
    <!-- Filter resource files -->
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  ....
</build>
```

After executing a mvn clean install I see that the main.properties in my target folder is replaced with the localhost value. However the property in my test.properties is not...

My first idea was to adapt the resources as this:

```
<properties>
    <host>localhost</host>
</properties>

<build>  
  <resources>
    <!-- Filter resource files -->
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
    <resource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
  </resources>
  ....
</build>
```

When building now, the test.properties file is replaced with the localhost value, but is placed into the classes folder in the target. In test-classes, there is still the test.properties file without the replaced value...

Is there a way to also replace the value in the test-classes folder?
My idea is to work on my local server with the localhost value without specifying it as a parameter and to overwrite this value with an alternate host when performing integration tests against a test server. In this case I specify the value -Dhost=<> on our continuous integration system.

Comment: If you are using Spring Framework, you should checkout the `@PropertySources` annotation. It allows you to specify few `@PropertySource` annotations which loads the properties file for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work (although test.properties will not end up in your classes folder and test-classes would have both test.properties and main.properties with the replaced value which I think was what you wanted but wasn't sure).

```
<resources>
    <!-- Filter resource files -->
    <resource>
      <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
<testResources>
    <!-- Filter test resource files -->
    <testResource>
      <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
      <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
```

Also, you may want to have two properties, `${host}` (referenced in host.properties) and `${test.host}` (referenced in test.properties), otherwise if you specify `-Dhost` during an integration build it will replace the value in both the host.properties and the test.properties.  This way you can specify `-Dtest.host` to change which host you are using for integration tests but not the host that is set when you deploy.

Comment: Thanks, this exactly what I needed! Just one remark, inside testResources, only testResource elements are allowed, not resource elements like mentioned in the example.

Comment: Thanks, cleaned up my answer.